# See variable values in developer tools for Django templates

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a template in Django which uses some variables.  For example, I use

```
{% with swatch_matrix=item_group.get_swatch_matrix %}
```

Without rendering this on-screen is there a way to use the developer tools, or something else, to check what value is being generated here?

Comment: No, since Django's template rendering is done at the *server side*. It only sends text back, the entire "context" that generated that string is "gone". The browser never sees the variables that were used in rendering the template since the server only answers with the caontent of the page.

Comment: Thank you.  Glad I didn't spend too much more time looking for this information in the dev tools.